# How to solve the "Wall of Pink" in Github for Windows?

Tags: windows, github

I'm using Github for Windows on Windows 7, sometimes it shows a wall of pink of some file, even that file has not been modified at all (as the following pic shows). I found [an article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx) talking about this, but I don't find a good solution.
Is there a way to make Github for windows work correctly rather than change the **CRLF** chars to **LF** in my file? I like **CRLF**....

[image: wall of pink]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I like CRLF....

Everybody does on Windows ;-)

Except that Git prefers to internally store textual content with LF line ending delimiters.

However, you can have both: CRLF in your working directory and LF in the git object database. There's a git built-in mechanism that facilitates that for you.

Indeed, as stated in **[Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx)**,

> *[...]you can do what GitHub for Windows suggests with text=auto (and create a **.gitattributes** file per repo containing the following lines).*
>
> ```
> # Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization 
> * text=auto
> ```
>
> *What's **text=auto** do?*
>
> This ensures that all files that git considers to be text will have
>   normalized (LF) line endings in the repository. The core.eol
>   configuration variable controls which line endings git will use for
>   normalized files in your working directory; the default is to use the
>   native line ending for your platform, or CRLF if core.autocrlf is set.

Another very useful piece of content is Tim Clem's post **[Mind the End of Your Line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)**. This brilliantly explains the whys and hows of Git line endings.

### Update

> nulltoken, I have .gitattributes in my project folder, and it has text=auto, but the github client just show me pink walls again and again.

Following your comment above, below some additional points to consider. This will require you to switch to command line in order to run some git commands.

- Make sure that the `.gitattributes` file is committed and not only lies in your project folder.
- In order not to loose anything, make sure that you do not have any pending changes (eg. running `git status` should output something like `nothing to commit, working directory clean`)
- Run `git checkout-index --force *`. This will recreate all your files in your working directory, taking into account the directives in the `.gitattributes` file. Once this is done, every text file in your working directory WILL bear CRLF line endings and `git status` should still consider the workdir as clean.
- The Wall of Pink shouldn't appear from now on when creating new commits.

**Note:** The wall of pink may still appear while displaying the changes between two commits in your history that were created before the commit containing the `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: > "Everybody does on Windows ;-)" I use Windows and don't like CRLF. :P

Comment: Using two chars for newlines is just silly and wasteful, but I couldn't care less as long as my editors and text viewers know it means a newline either way.

Comment: @CareyGregory but Github for windows cares and sometimes it couldn't make diff correctly!

Comment: nulltoken, I have **.gitattributes** in my project folder, and it has **text=auto**, but the github client just show me pink walls again and again.

Comment: @zhangxaochen The answer has been updated with new tools to fight the Wall of Pink ;-)

Comment: @nulltoken thx for your update, when I tried `git checkout-index --force *`, cmd line says **git checkout-index: * is not in the cache**,  what should I do?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Strange. Would `git checkout-index --force --all` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file in the Notepad++.
2. Go to Edit/EOL Conversion.
3. Click to the UNIX/OSX Format.
4. Save the file.